# .gradle folder in project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Using `gradlew` with `gradle 2.13`. So I noticed that there is a `.gradle` folder in both my project and my home folder. For some reason, having the project `.gradle` folder is causing an odd issue with my build. I have a complicated gradle build script that downloads artifacts from a repository and package them into an AAR file but the first time the build ran, it didn't include the downloaded artifacts and there is no build error. The same exact build command ran the 2nd time will include the artifacts. Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: I'm Facing a lot of issues with the latest gradle, Most of my issues resolved with invalidating caches. In `Android studio --> File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart` which will clears all the cached dependencies . So, When the studio restarts it will freshly sync all your dependencies. Give it a try if you havn't done it already.

Comment: Well, I am doing the build from command line, not Android Studio, so I am not sure this will help but good suggestion though.